# Show that Newton's Method converges in one step

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

Suppose that $A$ is a real $m \times n$ matrix, $m <n$, of full rank (this means that $A$ has full row rank).

Let $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{2}||Ax-b||_2^2$.

Show that Newton's method solves $\nabla \phi(x)=0$ in one step.

I am confused because I am not sure how to even take the gradient of $\phi(x)$. If someone could demonstrate, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the [Gâteaux-Derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gâteaux_derivative)

Answer (score 1):

Noting that $\phi(x) = {1 \over 2} \langle Ax-b, Ax-b\rangle =
{1 \over 2} (\langle x, A^T A x\rangle -2\langle x, A^T b\rangle + \|b\|^2 )$, expand $\phi(x+h)-\phi(x)$.

This will have a linear term and a term bounded by $\|h\|^2$. This shows that $\phi$ is differentiable and the linear part will be the derivative.